# returning time 3 hours behind date('l dS \o\f F Y h:i:s A')

Tags: php, xampp

Here the php function `date('l dS \o\f F Y h:i:s A')` is returning time 3 hour behind of my system time.why this is happening any body please answer...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your timezone is set incorrectly, have a read: [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: my reputation goes -5 down :(.i hate stack over flow rules.

Answer (score 0):

i have got correct answer by adding `date_default_timezone_set('');` function just above my date function `date('l dS \o\f F Y h:i:s A');`